# Is itertools combinations always sorted

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have **sorted** array from which I want to get all `itertools.combinations` of, say, 3 elements.

```
from itertools import combinations
start = 5
end = start+4
some_pos_number = 3
inds = list(combinations(range(start,end),some_pos_number))

>>>inds
[(5, 6, 7), (5, 6, 8), (5, 7, 8), (6, 7, 8)]
```

Is all of these combinations will always be sorted?

Comment: What sorted ness are you talking about? That each combination itself is sorted, or that the sequence of combinations is sorted?

Comment: @KellyBundy each combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

> `itertools.combinations(iterable, r)`
>
> Return *r* length subsequences of elements from the input *iterable*.
>
> The combination tuples are emitted in lexicographic ordering according to the order of the input *iterable*. So, if the input *iterable* is sorted, the output tuples will be produced in sorted order.

So the individual combinations will be internally sorted (being subsequences of a sorted iterable), and the sequence of combinations will itself be sorted too.

Comment: Adding to this, try: `reversed(range(start,end))`